# Stop google script from duplicating events transferred from sheets to calendar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, google-calendar-api

I've searched SO and this topic has come up before but I have yet to find anything that works for me. I have a google sheets document where I keep track of events and dates those events start. I set up some script to transfer any events I create in the sheets doc over to a calendar. The problem I'm having is anytime that script runs, it adds everything that's on the sheet. That's a problem because it's creating duplicates every time it runs. Is there a way to set this up so that my script only adds new events that don't already exist on my calendar.

Here is my code:

```
function createCalendarEvent(){
  var ctCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('v6utsrj3up5givjadrd1ce83qs@group.calendar.google.com');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var event = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var complete ="Added";
  var showCheck = [];
  event.splice(0,1);

for(x=0; x<event.length;x++){
  var showNumber = [9];
  if(stopDuplicate == complete){
    showCheck.push(showNumber);
  }
  var newEvent = event[x];
  var eventName = newEvent[10];
  var eventStart = newEvent[11];
  var stopDuplicate = newEvent[14]

if(showCheck.indexOf(showNumber == 0)) 
{
  showCheck.push(showNumber);
  var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + x, numColumns );
  ctCalendar.createAllDayEvent(eventName, eventStart);
  currentCell.setValue(complete); 
 }
}

}
```

[This is the Sheet With my events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Nqd.png)

Comment: You may want to check whether there is already same event existing, or add a column in the sheet act as a flag showing whether it has been already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('v6utsrj3up5givjadrd1ce83qs@group.calendar.google.com');
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const numColumns = sh.getLastColumn();
  const evs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, numColumns).getValues();
  const sr = 2;
  evs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[14] != "Done") {
      cal.createAllDayEvent(r[10],r[11]);
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 15).setValue("Done");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. It looks like I was over complicating it perhaps? Definitely much cleaner code. Thanks!